# How to find out DC's dimensions?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

Let's say I have a handle to device context (naturally, in Windows environment):

```
HDC hdc;
```

How can I get the width and height of it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A device context (DC) is a structure that defines a set of graphic objects and their associated attributes, and the graphic modes that affect output.

By width and height I'm guessing you are referring to the bitmap painted ? 
If so then i guess you can try the following :

```
BITMAP structBitmapHeader;
memset( &structBitmapHeader, 0, sizeof(BITMAP) );

HGDIOBJ hBitmap = GetCurrentObject(hDC, OBJ_BITMAP);
GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &structBitmapHeader);

//structBitmapHeader.bmWidth
//structBitmapHeader.bmHeight
```

Comment: This answer does not work with a printer page. I posted another answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77095378/2527795

Answer (score 11):

I also know little about GDI, but it seems [GetDeviceCaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144877(v=VS.85).aspx) might do the trick.

Comment: Specifically, `GetDeviceCaps(hdc, HORZRES)` and `GetDeviceCaps(hdc, VERTRES)` are most likely what's desired.

Comment: GetDeviceCaps(hdc,*) returns the screen dimensions regardless of the window size.  KevenK and msandiford's GetClientRect(WindowFromDC(hdc),&r) does the trick though.

Answer (score 6):

This simple piece of code I use always to get the dimensions of the rendering area, when I have only the HDC.
First, you must get a HWND from the HDC - is simple, then you can get the client rect of this HWND:

```
RECT    rcCli;          
GetClientRect(WindowFromDC(hdc), &rcCli);
// then you might have: 
nWidth = rcCli.right-rcCli.left; 
nHeight  = rcCli.bottom-rcCli.top;
```

Comment: This will only work when DC is associated with a window. For other cases (e.g. DC obtained from CreateCompatibleDC()) WindowFromDC() will return NULL.

Answer (score 1):

As a disclaimer, I know nothing about GDI or what you have to work with in your application. I'm just trying to be helpful if possible.

That said, I found a link which seems to suggest that it's appropriate to use `GetClientRect` to get the size of the drawing area:

```
RECT clientRect;

GetClientRect(hWnd,&clientRect);
```

http://www.toymaker.info/Games/html/gdi.html#winsize

Comment: This answer is wrong. `GetClientRect()` takes `HWND`, not `HDC`.

Answer (score 1):

but if get Calculator' window_dc dimension, it will failed at “GetCurrentObject” or "GetObject", i think maybe the window attribute include "ws_ex_noredirectionbitmap", how to get dismension in this case?

```
HDC win_dc = ::GetWindowDC(hwnd);
BITMAP bm = { 0 };
HGDIOBJ hBitmap = GetCurrentObject(win_dc, OBJ_BITMAP);
if (hBitmap)
{
    if (GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &bm))
    {
        windc_dimension.cx = bm.bmWidth;
        windc_dimension.cy = bm.bmHeight;
    }
}
```

Comment: The client are is invisible for [WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38179033/when-should-ws-ex-noredirectionbitmap-be-used).

Answer (score 0):

You could `WindowFromDC(...)` to get the DC's window if it's associated with a window.  You could then use @KevinK's answer to get the client rect from this.

Answer (score 0):

I am drawing on two possible contexts: Bitmap (2480x3508) and printer page (4961x7016).

Bitmap dimensions return wrong dimensions (1x1) for the printer page. `GetDeviceCaps` returns correct dimensions for the printer page, but returns wrong dimensions (screen dimensions) for the bitmap.

This function returns correct dimensions for both a bitmap and a printer page. Probably doesn't work for other contexts.

```
std::pair<int, int> getDrawingAreaDimensions(HDC context)
{
    // Drawing area is a bitmap
    {
        BITMAP header;
        ZeroMemory(&header, sizeof(BITMAP));

        HGDIOBJ bmp = GetCurrentObject(context, OBJ_BITMAP);
        GetObject(bmp, sizeof(BITMAP), &header);
        const int width = header.bmWidth;
        const int height = header.bmHeight;
        if (width > 1 && height > 1) {
            return {width, height};
        }
    }

    // Drawing area is a printer page
    const int width = GetDeviceCaps(context, HORZRES);
    const int height = GetDeviceCaps(context, VERTRES);
    return {width, height};
}
```