# SetWindowLong with GWL_EXSTYLE and WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP

Tags: windows, winapi

I change extended window style from 0 to WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP by calling

```
SetWindowLong(wnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP);
```

the return value is zero which means the function failed and GetLastError() returns 87 indicates "the parameter is incorrect".

any idea what's wrong with my code?

Comment: see also When should WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP be used? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38179033/when-should-ws-ex-noredirectionbitmap-be-used

Comment: Looks like this style can only be set on CreateWindow

Comment: thanks @Ben, I'm using it for window layering with DirectComposition.

Comment: `SetWindowLong()` can return 0 on success if the previous value was 0. You could probably juggle `SetLastError()`s to check for an explicit failure, [but it's probably better to assume the function cannot fail](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140203-00/?p=1893#comment-1104333)...

Comment: Some style flags can only be specified in the CreateWindowEx() call.  WS_EX_LAYERED is a good example.  This one certainly fits the same bill.  Doing it later requires entirely too much non-trivial internal reorganization, the redirect bitmap was already created and unspeakable DWM and DirectX stuff set up.  It is a little sloppy that this isn't documented, they do chip away at limitations like this however.  Do favor SetWindowLongPtr() btw.

Comment: @andlabs, I set last error with 19999 before calling SetWindowLong, the GetLastError() return 87 indicates "the parameter is incorrect".

Comment: @HansPassant, SetWindowLongPtr is the same :(

Comment: Yeah, sure.  You'll have to do this when you create the window.

Comment: got it, thanks to all. :-)

Comment: @HansPassant There are no restrictions on setting `WS_EX_LAYERED` with `SetWindowLongPtr`, the docs for `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` even say that you can do it.

Comment: @hiro The advice about SetWindowLongPtr is wider than this problem. Do take heed of it.

Comment: Hmm, I missed that memo.  They do chip away at it, Aero probably made it a lot easier.  Okay, WS_EX_APPWINDOW then.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, what you mean "SetWindowLongPtr is wider than this problem"? are you suggesting this can be done by SetWindowLongPtr???

Comment: No. I'm saying that it's a separate issue that you have not yet faced

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, can you give me some info or link about this issue?

Comment: A websearch will help. Did you do this yet? The difference is that SWLP operates on pointer sized values, and SWL operates on 32 bit values. Hence pointer truncation is possible with SWL on 64 bit.